# How to get the result value of Alamofire.request().responseJSON in swift 2?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, alamofire

I have a question about the new version of Alamofire for Swift 2

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject])
        .responseJSON { (request, response, result) -> Void in
            let dico = result as? NSDictionary
            for (index, value) in dico! {
                print("index : \(index)     value : \(value)")
            }
    }
```

In this section I would like to cast the result in to a NSDictionary. But When I compile and put a breakpoint, the debugger says that dico is nil. If I use debugDescription to print result, it is not nil and contains what I expected
How can I cast the Result variable?

Comment: Try `if let dico = result as? [String: AnyObject] { ... }`

Comment: If that doesn't execute, it's because the result was nil (or not downcastable to a dictionary). You should check to see what's in `error`.

Comment: Also, worth noting that dictionaries have keys, not indexes.

Comment: Thank you @mattt for your answer. I find how to do it. I use what you said but it didn't work, and when I do: 
if let dico = result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {} 
and just 'replace' result by 'result.value' it work find

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The accepted answer works great but with the introduction of Alamofire 3.0.0 there are some breaking changes that affects this implementation.
The [migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) has further explanations but i will highlight the ones related to the actual solution.

- [Response](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#response)
  *All response serializers (with the exception of response) return a generic Response struct.*
- [Response type](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#result-type)
  *The Result type has been redesigned to be a double generic type that does not store the NSData? in the `.Failure` case.*

Also take in count that Alamofire treats any completed request to be successful, regardless of the content of the response. So you need to chain a `.validate()` before `.responseJSON()` to hit the `.Failure` case.
Read more about it [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#validation).

Updated code:

```swift
let url = "http://api.myawesomeapp.com"
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let data):
        let json = JSON(data)
        let name = json["name"].stringValue
        print(name)
    case .Failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

For reference:

- Xcode 7.3 (Swift 2.2)
- Alamofire 3.3.1
- SwiftyJSON 2.3.3

Comment: Alamofire won't hit the .Failure case unless you chain in .validate() before .responseJSON{}, so it will treat all completed requests as .Success, even if the HTTP status code is not in the 200 range: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#validation

Comment: Thanks @ChrisTrevarthen, didn't note that. Answer updated with your clarification.

Comment: In Alamofire 4.0, data is now 'Any'. How do you handle that?

Comment: this worked for me even in Alamofire 4.0 and promisekit

Comment: @osrl it appears that with Alamofire 4.0 you can access `response.result.isSuccess` or `response.result.isFailure` instead.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Using `.validate()` to hit `.failure(let error)` case.

Answer (score 39):

If you don't mind using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/xcode7) library, here's a working example in Xcode 7 Beta 5 + Alamofire 2.0.0-beta.1 + SwiftyJSON (xcode7 branch)

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).responseJSON { (_, _, result) in
    switch result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            let name = json["name"].string
        case .Failure(_, let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Edit:

Updated [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) git page

Comment: The SwifyJSON link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

You can now achieve most of the required behaviour out of the box without the need for SwiftyJSON for example. My OAuthTokenResponse is a simple struct that is Codable. The Alamofire library 5.2.2 lets you respond using the 'responseDecodable'

If you have say a struct that looks like this:

```
struct OAuthTokenResponse : Codable
{
    var access_token:String?
    var token_type:String?
    var expires_in:Int?
    var scope:String?
}
```

And then in your network call (using Alamofire)

```
let request = AF.request(identityUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
    request
        .validate()
        .responseDecodable { (response:AFDataResponse<OAuthTokenResponse>) in
            
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let jwt = try decode(jwt: data.access_token!) // example
                    self.connected = true
                    print(jwt)
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    self.connected = false
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                    self.connected = false
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        
        }
```

In the above code, the success case automatically deserialises your JSON using the decodable protocol into your struct. Any errors will result in the error case being hit instead.