# Can't access JSON using SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swifty-json

I am trying to access the JSON that I get via Alamofire:

```
func getDataFromServer() {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, websiteURL, parameters: myParameters) .responseString {
        (response) -> Void in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)
            self.parseJSON(json)
        }
    }
}
```

,and the JSON that is being returned to me looks something like this:

```
{  
"status":"success",
"object":[  
  {  
     "name":"Bob",
     "age":"20 ",
  },
  {  
     "name": "Jane",
     "age":"25"
  },
]
}
```

and I am using SwiftyJSON to access the names:

```
func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
    for result in json["object"].arrayValue {
        print(result["name"].stringValue)
    }
}
```

but it is not printing anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The json format is not correct. Could this be the problem? The correct son format should be

{
  "status": "success",
  "object": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": "20 "
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane",
      "age": "25"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I made a mistake typing out the JSON manually, but I managed to fix my problem. I was returning the data as an string instead of a JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`responseJSON` should be used instead of `responseString`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "object": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": "20 ",

    },
    {
      "name": "Jane",
      "age": "25"
    }, <--Delete this comma

  ]
}
```

Comment: Opps, sorry. Was manually typing out the JSON. But the comma isn't there in the actual JSON, and the JSON is a valid JSON.

Comment: @manohjay Ok, then the Almonfire doesn't return `NSData`,
see here example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018741/how-to-get-the-result-value-of-alamofire-request-responsejson-in-swift-2

Comment: I managed to fix my problem. I was returning the data as an string instead of a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out what was wrong with my code. When I did a POST request using Alamofire, I was returning the data back as a string: .responseString instead of JSON: .responseJSON

working code:

```
func getDataFromServer() {
Alamofire.request(.POST, websiteURL, parameters: myParameters) .responseJSON {
    (response) -> Void in
    if let value = response.result.value {
        let json = JSON(value)
        self.parseJSON(json)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `responseString` with `responseJSON`