# Can't pull value from json data

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I've seen a number of questions and answers addressing this.  I've tried it and I can't figure it out. I've accessed my owner server's responseJSON no problem.  But now I am trying to consume a 3rd party API and am having trouble.  I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

let json = JSON(data: data)

this is what json looks like:

```
{"maxResults":50,"startAt":0,"isLast":true,"values":[{"id":1,"self":"https://stackrank.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/board/1","name":"JI board","type":"scrum"},{"id":2,"self":"https://stackrank.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/board/2","name":"Board2","type":"scrum"}]}
```

Why can't i access any of the values?
json["maxResults"].numberValue gives me '0' 
json["values"].arrayValue     give me an empty array []

I've seen a bunch of answers regarding the encoding etc...but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is the snippet from Alamofire showing the response format:

```
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
  response in
  switch response.result {
  case .success:
    success(response.data!)
```

Comment: don't use SwiftyJson's JSON() object?  I tried what you suggested.  I am getting "Type 'Any' has no subscript members when I try json["values"] now.

Comment: Try casting to [String: AnyObject] and got Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10ba9dd88) to 'NSDictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you are getting must not be a SwiftJSON object.  Here's playground code that works perfectly (requires SwiftyJSON.swift to be in the Sources folder):

```
let jsontext = "{\"maxResults\":50,\"startAt\":0,\"isLast\":true,\"values\":[{\"id\":1,\"self\":\"https://stackrank.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/board/1\",\"name\":\"JI board\",\"type\":\"scrum\"},{\"id\":2,\"self\":\"https://stackrank.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/board/2\",\"name\":\"Board2\",\"type\":\"scrum\"}]}"

let data = jsontext.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = JSON(data)

print(json["maxResults"].intValue)
print(json["values"].arrayValue)
```

This works perfectly.

In terms of the raw data, here's what [another SO question proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018741/how-to-get-the-result-value-of-alamofire-request-responsejson-in-swift-2):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let data):
        let json = JSON(data)
        let maxResults = json["maxResults"].intValue
        let values = json["values"].arrayValue
        print(maxResults)
    case .Failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, David.  Your answer did two things: 1) understand the pattern better; 2) discover my SwiftyJSON version was outdated.  Your answer helped me get this working.