# Login in with Alamofire : Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x103860210) to 'NSString' (0x102e66c40)

Tags: swift, casting, alamofire

Hi I am new to programming and I'm stuck at this error. I am logging in from Xcode to MySQL, but I am unable to move on to home page. My code works fine in PHP and I am unable to login.

Below is my code:

```
@IBAction func Login(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let URL_USER_REGISTER = "http://localhost/login.php"

    let parameters: Parameters = [
            "username":username.text!,                
            "password":password.text!                
    ]

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
    {
        response in
        //printing response
        print(response)

        if let result = response.result.value
        {
            let resultValue:String = result as! String;

            if (resultValue == "login_success")
            {
                //login is successful
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();

                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns:

> login_success Could not cast value of type
>   '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x103860210) to 'NSString'
>   (0x102e66c40).

That's why I am unable to move on to my home page.

Comment: Clearly, the error means that the `response.result.value` should be a Dictionary but not a String. `let resultValue:String = result as! String;` it the problem.

Comment: i tried but it still give me the same error @AhmadF

Comment: Isn't due to your "//printing response
                print(response)"?
It's not String type so it would be the source of this error

Comment: Well, what's the output of `print(response)`?

Comment: Try to print(resultValue) because the input of print() should be printable as float, string, int or any other type.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print

Comment: it prints "login_success" - derived from my php code and the error mention above @AhmadF

Comment: Can you give us the output of login.php so we can evaluate your JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

Because your result is dictionary type not string type:-

use this

```
let resultValue = result as! [String:Any];
```

later you can get value of login_success based on key

Answer (score 0):

Try another way of retrieving your http result and adding a failure enclosure. Not knowing the output format of you login.php doesn't help but it should look like this:

```
@IBAction func Login(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let URL_USER_REGISTER = "http://localhost/login.php"


    let parameters: Parameters=[

        "username":username.text!,

        "password":password.text!

         ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, URL_USER_REGISTER, parameters: parameters, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).responseJSON { result in
        switch result {
            case .Success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                let resultValue = json["value"].string
                if (resultValue == "login_success")
                {
                    //login is successful
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            case .Failure(_, let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

Source: [How to get the result value of Alamofire.request().responseJSON in swift 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018741/how-to-get-the-result-value-of-alamofire-request-responsejson-in-swift-2)

Comment: i receive an error "Extra argument in call" and apparently its for my url and param @Delparo

Comment: Which version of Alamofire are you currently using? @nrsyaf

Comment: Alamofire', '~> 4.3 @Delparo

Comment: do i have to import SwiftyJSON? @Delparo

Comment: No, I don't think you need to install SwiftyJSON, but the piece of code I provided you is for Alamofire 2.3. I will edit in few minutes my post.

Comment: Try replacing (_,_,result) by result. And can you edit your post to show the output of login.php, please.

Comment: I still end up with the error "extra argument in call" @Robin Delaporte

Comment: Try to find which extra argument you are adding. Here is the document of alamofire 4. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md.